# Nesting simpleType within complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

The code below gives me the following error during validation. Does it mean that I cannot nest simpleType elements within complexType elements?

`Error - Line 18, 17: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 17; s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'sequence' must match (annotation?, (element | group | choice | sequence | any)*). A problem was found starting at: simpleType.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/carType"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <element name="carType">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <simpleType name="colour">
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <enumeration value="blue" />
                        <enumeration value="yellow" />
                        <enumeration value="green" />
                        <enumeration value="black" />
                        <enumeration value="white" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
                <simpleType name="body">
                    <restriction base="string">
                        <enumeration value="sedan" />
                        <enumeration value="hatchback" />
                    </restriction>
                </simpleType>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. You construct complex types from simple types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're close.  Just make two minor adjustments to your XSD:**

1. Where you have `<simpleType name="colour">`, instead declare a
   `colour` element:

   ```
       <element name="colour">
         <simpleType>
   ```
2. Similarly, where you have `<simpleType name="body">`, instead
   declare a `body` element:

   ```
       <element name="body">
         <simpleType>
   ```

**Altogether, then:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/carType"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <element name="carType">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element name="colour">
          <simpleType>
            <restriction base="string">
              <enumeration value="blue" />
              <enumeration value="yellow" />
              <enumeration value="green" />
              <enumeration value="black" />
              <enumeration value="white" />
            </restriction>
          </simpleType>
        </element>
        <element name="body">
          <simpleType>
            <restriction base="string">
              <enumeration value="sedan" />
              <enumeration value="hatchback" />
            </restriction>
          </simpleType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```